# Call from one JSP file to another JSP

Tags: java, jsp

I need to call from one JSP to another, do some stuff over there..

I am inside the caller jsp, inside his handleReqeust(HttpServletReqeust request)
method I am trying to forward the request to another JSP, to call the other JSP file to his handleRequest(HttpServletReqeust request) off course with the request object

I tried it:

```
 RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/theSecondJspFile.jsp");
      if (dispatcher != null)
         dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

but to make it work I need for it the object response, but I don't have it,
I am sure I missed something basic, but what?

From my question you can see, I don't have solid backround in java, so please correct me, or refer me to good guide if you feel it necessary

Thanks.

-------------------Edit--------------------------------------

I don't need a redirect, I just want to call another JSP file to his handleRequest method
I think it relate to HTML

Comment: Are you trying to create a hyperlink?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added empty Iframe, and set his URL when I needed to call him

Answer (score 0):

What I can make out of your question is that you need to redirect to a secondpage.html from firstpage.html with some data. You can use both GET or POST method to send the data.

For the GET method just redirect to secondpage,html?data=value. The data will be available in the HttpRequest parameter in the controller of the secondpage.html where it can be used as required.

For the POST method you would need to post the data (using a form on firstpage.html) to secondpage.html. In the controller of the secondpage.html the data should be available in a similar way as before.

Answer (score 0):

To include another JSP in a jsp :

```
<jsp:include page="foo.jsp"/>
```

You can find some reference material [here](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/tags/12/syntaxref1214.html).

Comment: Let say I have a class in foo.jsp which named myClass, how can I call the class after I included his jsp file?

Comment: @Delashmate Can you add the code in your question, it will help in solving the problem

Comment: You should not define a class in a JSP. This is really bad design.

Answer (score 0):

I can not be sure, but what I think you are trying to do is to include a jsp page on to your jsp page and use the the objects and other variables declared in the first jsp page in your second.

`<%@ include file="mypage.jsp" %>`  should help you do this.

If this is not what you are looking for, please make your question tad bit more clear. some code will help really.

Answer (score 0):

JSPs are supposed to be used to present the final result. JSPs are not supposed to be part of business tasks leading to this result. There you use normal Java classes for, starting with a servlet class. Let the HTTP request (the one which you enter in browser address bar or specify in some HTML link or form) point to the URL of the servlet instead. This way you can write Java code in the servlet the usual way to invoke other Java classes/methods and finally forward the request to a certain JSP file based on the outcome of the result and then just let that JSP present the final result.

To start with servlets, I'd suggest to read [our Servlets info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info).